# How and when are stock shares created? Destroyed?

Tags: stocks, dilution

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but someone (quite possibly me) is confused about whether stock shares can be arbitrary manufactured at any time and in any quantity, or whether they in fact represent partial ownership of the company and can be reorganized (eg, repurchased by the company, or company-owned shares sold) but not multiplied after the issue.

This gets to the basic question of what a share "is". I thought I understood that, but possibly not, and if I'm wrong I'd like to be corrected.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "arbitrary manufactured at any time and in any quantity, or whether they in fact represent partial ownership of the company."  Change in the number of shares can occur from forward and reverse splits and secondary offerings.  Shorting creates additional synthetic long shares and AFAIC, that's somewhat artificial.

Comment: That was my understanding. But there seems to be confusion on this point (see the question about dilution), and getting an explicit explanation in place here that we could refer people to -- and that might correct anything I'm overlooking -- seems worthwhile. I could write an answer to myself as a starting point to provoke discussion, but I'd rather not lead the discussion toward my errors (if any) more than  I must, so I'd rather wait for others to do so and just ask clarifying questions if needed.

Comment: I don't feel I understand this well enough to write a proper answer, but the concepts of authorized but unissued share capital, and when a company can change them, seem relevant. Essentially, I think given sufficient approval, a company can choose to create more shares and then sell them.

Comment: I'm less than convinced of that unless those shares come out of portions of the company not sold in the original issue (essentially retained shares of ownership, whether already in actual share form or not). That's one of the points we need clarified since we both think we understand but neither is sure. (Darned auto-incorrect.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, we both think that a company could be created with 1000 shares, with 500 handed out to the original owners and 500 shares retained/not issued. Then they can later sell those 500. Where we differ is that I think that they could also, at least sometimes, create another 500 shares for 1500 total and also sell those, whereas you don't think that. Is that correct? (cont..)

Comment: TBH I'm not even sure the difference matters to anything. The ownership proportions are what matter and those only change when any shares the company has get transferred to other people. Whether it can create/destroy them as needed, or just has to start by issuing a huge number of shares to begin with, seems irrelevant.

Comment: A share is fractional ownership of a company, right?  The corporate bylaws authorize the *creation* of an initial  8000 shares of stock.  The Board of Directors authorizes an initial *sale* of 6000 shares. You buy 1000 shares, so own 16.67% of the company.  The board authorizes the *sale* of the additional 2000 shares.  Now your fraction is down to 12.5%, but each share is worth more. That is because the company is worth more due to all the extra cash.  Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: There is confusion about whether more shares can be created later, by whom, selling what, and what that does (if anything) to value of existing holdings. With two of us pretty convinced we know what we're talking about but neither of us certain, and a lack of agreement, we need a consensus answer from the community. See the dilution question for history of what we're trying to resolve, but I think this should be answered as a separate question which informs the answer to that one, so we know we're all talking about the same things.

Comment: For example, in [this press release](https://www.credit-suisse.com/about-us-news/en/articles/media-releases/capital-increase-share-placement-final-terms-long-202211.html), "Credit Suisse Group [...] issued 462,041,884 new shares with a nominal value of CHF 0.04 each through an ordinary capital increase by way of a share placement to qualified investors. The number of issued shares of Credit Suisse Group AG thus increased to 3,112,789,604."

Comment: And [here](https://www.credit-suisse.com/media/assets/about-us/docs/investor-relations/corporate-and-share-information/share-information/share-capital-statistics/20210108-csgn-buyback-notice-en.pdf) is a declaration of intent to "cancel" shares once repurchased, which supports the idea that the number of shares is not constant.

Comment: I can see how you can cancel shares after repurchasing them; repurchase makes each outstanding share indirectly own a share of those shares. Then explicitly returning those shares to the percentage of the company not sold off as shares is essentially a bookkeeping transaction.

Comment: I can see how a company could resell shares it has repurchased, or issue new shares against the percentage of itself that wasn't previously public; that's the reverse and if one didn't count the cash raised it would reduce the value of a share by the same indirect ownership. (And the new shares could be a different class with its own price and dividends and what not,) But in the end there is only 100% of the company to be turned into (various kinds of) stock shares, right?

Comment: ... Should I copy all of that into the Question, or could someone just include these cases in their Answer? I thought it implicit in the question as written, and I wanted to avoid TL;DR...

Comment: I think it's worth expanding the question to clarify the points of confusion. From my perspective I don't really understand the concept of "percentage of itself that wasn't previously public". As you've already pointed out, if the company owns shares then the other shareholders indirectly own a share of those shares.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica A public company issuing shares is different to my question since a public company would issue shares at market value, meaning that investors worth won’t decrease, the real question is if they can do so below market value and decrease investors worth.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku It's the same mechanism if it's a private company (unless there's corruption or fraud). Suppose that the "owner" creates and sells additional shares for "market value". Then the _value_ of your ownership is the same since you own a smaller portion of a larger pie.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku e.g. if you own 10% of a $1M company ($100k) and the owner doubles the number of shares to sell at market value (for $1M cash), then you own 5% of a $2M company, which is still $100k.

Comment: @DStanley The point is that in that case “market value” is not defined so nothing stops the owner giving them away for free cause they feel like it, and not respect the other shareholders.

Comment: Why would they give away shares for free? If they're selling ownership then they are hopefully getting cash back so that they can grow the company. Can they sell shares for less than what they're worth? Certainly, but you own a portion of that capital as well.

Comment: Hmm. I _think_ the key point in @DStanley's scenario might be that the shares are replaced by an equivalent amount of cash, so the actual value represented by a share doesn't change. The same should happen if the company sells existing shares the it holds. Assuming that is correct,  *IF*  the company could be persuaded to give away part of itself then the actual value represented by a share would in fact decrease. Eg, in a stock split: the value is divided over twice as many shares, but since everyone who owns a share is given an additional share it comes out even. Yes? Maybe? Not exactly?

Comment: This is begging the question of how, outside of a stock split, a give-away could ever happen. The original question posits the whim of a majority stockholder trying to gift shares from the company rather than from his own holdings.

Comment: A stock split is not a share-giveaway either. All it does is changes the per share value of the stock - the overall value does not change.  If you had 10 shares worth $10 each ($100 total) and it splits 2:1, you now have 20 shares worth $5 each (still $100 total)

Comment: And I think the answer may just have been given: The company could set fire to it's computer center too, producing a loss, but doing so at the direction of an investor without a damned good reason is likely to draw fraud charges...

Comment: (Not saying a split is a giveaway, just trying to draw analogies to how the math works out.)

Comment: Yes a company that "gave away" part of its ownership would dilute other shareholders, but that would likely be illegal, fraudulent, or both. It is not part of "normal" business operations.

Comment: Someone want to try to reduce this to an answer, or should I try to do so? I _think_ what this means is that deliberate stock value reduction, by dilution or any other mechanism, is simply Not Going To Happen.

Comment: Summarized into the dilution question; please check my reduction and comment if I've missed anything

Answer (score 2):

A share of stock - as you point out - is fractional ownership of a company. The terms of that ownership vary, but usually include voting on board members, a proportional share of any dividends, etc.

A company can generally create (issue) and sell new shares of stock as much as they want, subject to existing shareholder or board approval. This will dilute existing shareholders of course, but this doesn't necessarily mean the share price will go down. The company should be more valuable after this in total, as they got a huge pile of cash for those new shares.

Suppose the company has $100M in the bank, no employees, and no other assets. There are 1M shares of stock. Roughly you would expect those shares to be worth $100 each. Now the company issues and sells 500k more shares at the $100 market price. Now there are 1.5M shares and the company has $150M in the bank - still roughly $100 per share.

Comment: Thanks; that does resolve some of confusion about how dilution works. Note that if the company repurchases its own shares, that winds up being the same transformation in the other direction.

Comment: Subsidiary question: If dilution occurs, what typically happens to dividends per share? Does the company wind up with more dividend costs per year, do they adjust the size of the dividend to distribute the same budget across the larger owner pool, or is this on a case by case basis? (I suspect the latter.)

Comment: @keshlam The company revisits their dividend decision based on the changed circumstances. Generally, a company would issue and sell shares if it needs cash for some reason and so a dividend may not make sense in that case. If the company issues stock to acquire another company, there may be no reason to change the total amount of the dividend, but that will result in less per share in the short term. Presumably, the company is only doing it because they believe it helps in the long term.